# Do you have tips for trusting/assuming that recursion works in Scheme?

Tags: loops, recursion, scheme

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around recursion in PLT Scheme.

For example, if you have this code (unfinished), that outputs a number of "*"'s and b number of "-"'s:

```
(define (stars-and-stripes a b)
(local ((define repeat (lambda(w n) (cond [(= n 0) ""] [(> n 0) (string-append w (repeat w (− n 1)))]))))
(cond
[(= 0 a) (cons (repeat "-" b) empty)]
[(= 0 b) (cons (repeat "∗" a) empty)]
[ (and (> a 0) (> b 0)) ... (stars-and-stripes (− a 1) b) ... (stars-and-stripes a (− b 1))...])))
```

How can I trust that this part works correctly?

```
(stars-and-stripes (− a 1) b) ... (stars-and-stripes a (− b 1))
```

This is a conceptual concept I've had trouble grasping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. The answer boils down to:

```
You can trust it due to the principle of induction for natural numbers.
```

That statement deserves an elaboration. Let us consider a simpler recursive function:

```
(define (mult3 n)
  (cond
    [(= n 0) 0]
    [else    (+ 3 (mult3 (- n 1)))]))
```

My claim is that `(mult3 n)` calculated n times 3 for all natural numbers n.
How does one prove a statement ending in " for all n" ?
Well, one must use induction.

The base case is n=0. What does `(mult3 0)` return? Since the n=0, the first cond-clause is used, and the result is 0. And since 3*0=0, we have that mult3 works in the base case.

For the induction step one assumes that the property is true for all numbers less than n, and must prove that implies the property is true for n.
In this case we must assume we can assume `(mult3 n-1)` returns 3*(n-1).

With that assumption we must consider what `(mult3 n)` returns.
Since m is not zero the second cond-clause is used. The value returned
is  `(+ 3 (mult3 (- n 1)))` and we have:

```
(mult3 n)  = (+ 3 (mult3 (- n 1))) 
           = (+ 3 3*(n-1))         ; by induction hypothesis
           = 3*n
```

For this example, your question is "How can I trust the expression (mult3 m-1)
works correctly?". The answer, is that you can trust it, due to the induction principle. In short: First check the base case(s), then check (mult3 n) under the assumption that (mult3 m) works for all m less than n.

In order to use the induction principle, it is important that the argument to the recursive function besomes smaller. In the mult3 example to n becomes n-1.
In the stars-and-stripe example either a or b becomes smaller in the recursive calls.

Is this explanation making sense?

Comment: I would agree completely with all of this, and I would insert more "proto-inductive" steps before going to induction. Convince yourself that it works for 1, and 2, and 3, before going to the inductive step. Indeed, you should probably be convinced *before* you get to the full induction step. The induction step completes the "proof", but doesn't (IMHO) help much with the actual "belief" part.

Comment: It also helps to run a few recursive programs in the Stepper in DrRacket. (And I am not just saying this because John joined the thread ;-) )
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3X07a-7YRM

Comment: This was super helpful guys- I understand recursion a lot better now. Thanks! (a large part of it is so magical)